# Flutter - image_cropper crashed with ActivityNotFound exception on Android

Tags: android, flutter

When I choose image from gallery or take photo from camera, what should've been done is cropping the image first before saving the image to the profile picture. But when I select the image from gallery, it instantly closed the app (lost connection to device).

Here is my code:

```
 class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 }

   enum AppState {
     cropped,
   }

 class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
   @override

   File? image;

   Future getImage() async {
     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
     final XFile? imagePicked = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

     cropImage(imagePicked!.path);

   }

   Future getCamera() async {
     final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
     final XFile? imageCamera = await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

     cropImage(imageCamera!.path);
    }

   Future cropImage(filePath) async {
     File? croppedImage = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: filePath,
        aspectRatioPresets: [
          CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
        ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
           toolbarTitle: 'Crop image',
           toolbarColor: Color(0xFF2481CF),
           toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
           initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
           lockAspectRatio: false),
       iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
         minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
       )
   );

   if (croppedImage != null) {
     setState(() {
       image = croppedImage;
     });
   }
 }
```

Here is the error log:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this in real device? I think is a emulator problem

Comment: Please share the error log?

Comment: I've updated my question, please have a look @rkumar1904

Comment: @aufa can you confirm the below code you've added
`
<activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
`

Comment: Seems to be activity not declared in manifest file

Comment: @rkumar1904 it's inside the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: what activity should be declared? @HardikMehta

Comment: @aufa : com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity

Comment: I've already declared it inside the AndroidManifest.xml @HardikMehta

Comment: can you check by   flutter clean and run again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this code:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

to your `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`